# SVG анимация заполнения

Tags: css, css3, html5, svg, анимация

Мне нужно сделать так,  как будто вода капает внутрь. 
В настоящее время это квадрат с волновой анимацией поверх логотипа.
Он правильно выполняет волновую анимацию, но я не могу заставить ее оставаться внутри капли, а также заполнять ее.
Я продвинулся в решении, но мне  нужно, чтобы внутри фактического логотипа было наполнение.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>SVG Line Animation Demo</title>

</head>
<body>
<style>

    .st0{fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:4;stroke-miterlimit:5;}
    .st1{fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:3;stroke-miterlimit:5;}

    #logo2 {
        width: 150px !important;
        height: 150px !important;
        position: relative;
        margin-top: -100px;
    }

    #banner {
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        background: #fff;
        overflow: hidden;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        z-index: -1;
        margin-bottom: -50px;
    }

    #banner .fill {
        animation-name: fillAction;
        animation-iteration-count: 1;
        animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.2, .6, .8, .4);
        animation-duration: 4s;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }

    #banner #waveShape {
        animation-name: waveAction;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        animation-timing-function: linear;
        animation-duration: 0.5s;
        width:300px;
        height: 150px;
        fill: #04ACFF;
    }

    @keyframes fillAction {
        0% {
            transform: translate(0, 150px);
        }
        100% {
            transform: translate(0, -5px);
        }
    }

    @keyframes waveAction {
        0% {
            transform: translate(-150px, 0);
        }
        100% {
            transform: translate(0, 0);
        }
    }

</style>

<div>
    <div id="banner">
        <div class="fill">

            <svg version="1.1" id="logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 136 195" style="enable-background:new 0 0 136 195;" xml:space="preserve">

                <path fill="#04ACFF" id="waveShape" d="M300,300V2.5c0,0-0.6-0.1-1.1-0.1c0,0-25.5-2.3-40.5-2.4c-15,0-40.6,2.4-40.6,2.4
    c-12.3,1.1-30.3,1.8-31.9,1.9c-2-0.1-19.7-0.8-32-1.9c0,0-25.8-2.3-40.8-2.4c-15,0-40.8,2.4-40.8,2.4c-12.3,1.1-30.4,1.8-32,1.9
    c-2-0.1-20-0.8-32.2-1.9c0,0-3.1-0.3-8.1-0.7V300H300z"/>
            </svg>
         </div>
    </div>        

    <svg version="1.1" id="logo2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 136 195" style="enable-background:new 0 0 136 195;" xml:space="preserve">

        <path class="st0" d="M68.2,6.7c0,0-62.4,70.9-62.4,124.7c0,32.3,28,58.4,62.4,58.4s62.4-26.2,62.4-58.4
    C130.7,77.6,68.3,6.7,68.2,6.7z"/>
        <g><path class="st1" d="M61,77.5c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5v20.6c2.7-3.6,7.6-5.7,13.1-5.7c12.2,0,19.4,6.9,19.4,18.7v37.2
        c0,0.8-0.7,1.5-1.5,1.5H75.6c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.4-1.5v-32c0-4.1-1.8-6.4-5-6.4c-5.8,0-6.7,5.7-6.7,5.7v32.7c0,0.8-0.7,1.5-1.5,1.5
        H43.1c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5V79c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5H61z"/></g>
    </svg>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/42013794/7394871

Answer (score 3):

Изменения вашего кода:

- удалить область просмотра (мне просто проще использовать transform),
- сделать копию обоих, - капли и буквы "h",
- поместите этот объединенный путь в элемент `<clipPath>` внутри
  элемента `<defs>` в `<svg>` и присвойте ему идентификатор `"drop"`
- поместите групповой элемент `<g>` вокруг группы `<g class = "fill">`,
- обрезать вмещающий элемент , используя `drop`, и
- `scale` и `translate` обведенные черной линией `drop-and-h`, а также
  путь клипа `drop-and-h` на одинаковые величины, чтобы они были
  центрированы по форме волны.

```css
 .st0 {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000000;
      stroke-width: 4;
      stroke-miterlimit: 5;
    }
    .st1 {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000000;
      stroke-width: 3;
      stroke-miterlimit: 5;
    }
    #logo2 {
      width: 150px !important;
      height: 150px !important;
      position: relative;
      margin-top: -100px;
    }
    #banner {
      border-radius: 50%;
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
      background: #fff;
      overflow: hidden;
      backface-visibility: hidden;
      transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
      z-index: -1;
      margin-bottom: -50px;
    }
    #banner .fill {
      animation-name: fillAction;
      animation-iteration-count: 1;
      animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.2, .6, .8, .4);
      animation-duration: 4s;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
    #banner #waveShape {
      animation-name: waveAction;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      animation-timing-function: linear;
      animation-duration: 0.5s;
      width: 300px;
      height: 150px;
      fill: #04ACFF;
    }
    @keyframes fillAction {
      0% {
        transform: translate(0, 150px);
      }
      100% {
        transform: translate(0, -5px);
      }
    }
    @keyframes waveAction {
      0% {
        transform: translate(-150px, 0);
      }
      100% {
        transform: translate(0, 0);
      }
    }
```

```html
 <div>
    <div id="banner">
      <div>
        <svg version="1.1" id="logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" xml:space="preserve">

          <defs>
            <clipPath id="drop">
              <path transform="scale(0.75), translate(32,0)" d="M68.2,6.7c0,0-62.4,70.9-62.4,124.7c0,32.3,28,58.4,62.4,58.4s62.4-26.2,62.4-58.4
    C130.7,77.6,68.3,6.7,68.2,6.7z M61,77.5c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5v20.6c2.7-3.6,7.6-5.7,13.1-5.7c12.2,0,19.4,6.9,19.4,18.7v37.2
        c0,0.8-0.7,1.5-1.5,1.5H75.6c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.4-1.5v-32c0-4.1-1.8-6.4-5-6.4c-5.8,0-6.7,5.7-6.7,5.7v32.7c0,0.8-0.7,1.5-1.5,1.5
        H43.1c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5V79c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5H61z" />
            </clipPath>
          </defs>

          <g clip-path="url(#drop)">
            <g class="fill">
              <path fill="#04ACFF" id="waveShape" d="M300,300V2.5c0,0-0.6-0.1-1.1-0.1c0,0-25.5-2.3-40.5-2.4c-15,0-40.6,2.4-40.6,2.4
    c-12.3,1.1-30.3,1.8-31.9,1.9c-2-0.1-19.7-0.8-32-1.9c0,0-25.8-2.3-40.8-2.4c-15,0-40.8,2.4-40.8,2.4c-12.3,1.1-30.4,1.8-32,1.9
    c-2-0.1-20-0.8-32.2-1.9c0,0-3.1-0.3-8.1-0.7V300H300z" />
            </g>
          </g>
          <g transform="scale(0.75), translate(32,0)">
            <path class="st0" d="M68.2,6.7c0,0-62.4,70.9-62.4,124.7c0,32.3,28,58.4,62.4,58.4s62.4-26.2,62.4-58.4
    C130.7,77.6,68.3,6.7,68.2,6.7z" />
            <path class="st1" d="M61,77.5c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5v20.6c2.7-3.6,7.6-5.7,13.1-5.7c12.2,0,19.4,6.9,19.4,18.7v37.2
        c0,0.8-0.7,1.5-1.5,1.5H75.6c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.4-1.5v-32c0-4.1-1.8-6.4-5-6.4c-5.8,0-6.7,5.7-6.7,5.7v32.7c0,0.8-0.7,1.5-1.5,1.5
        H43.1c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5V79c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5H61z" />
          </g>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```